# Why is value undefined after subscribing to a service?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, undefined

I am subscribing to a service to grab a single Object from a json file. I then want to sort that object based on a value of a certain key. If I try to reference returned Object, I get an undefined error.

Example:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.teamName = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('team').toLowerCase();
    this.currAge = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('age').toLowerCase();
    this.currDiv = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('division').toLowerCase();
    this.getTeam(this.currAge, this.currDiv, this.teamName);
    this.sortTournaments();
  }
  getTeam(age: string, gender: string, teamName: string): void {
    this.standingService.getTeam(age, gender, teamName).subscribe({
      next: team => this.currTeam = team,
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
  }
  sortTournaments(): void{
    this.currTeam.past_tournaments.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.year - b.year;
    })
  }
```

I realize the issue is that getTeam() is asynchronous, but how can I solve that issue?

Comment: You should put any logic that requires `this.currTeam` to be defined in the `next` callback of the `subscribe` function. you can use blocks like this: `team => { // logic }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
Just call `this.sortTournaments()` inside of your Observers `next` method after the value is set.

```
next: team => { 
  this.currTeam = team;
  this.sortTournaments();
},
```

Options 2:
Turn the Observable into a promise, something like

```
this.standingService.getTeam(age, gender, teamName).toPromise()
  .then(team => this.currTeam = team)
  .then(() => this.sortTournaments())
  .catch(err => this.errorMessage = err)
```

Comment: Following up very late, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.